# CSS flexbox responsive div

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following codepen: http://codepen.io/AlexanderWeb00/pen/NpKyRm

below 500px I would like to have 2 divs next to each other so I have changed the width to 50%

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
}

// * {
//   box-sizing: border-box;
// }

.container__item {
    align-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 1;
    font-size: 3em;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 1em;

    // maintain aspect ratio 
    width: 24%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){ 
  .container__item {
      width: 50%;
  }
}
```

but they only stuck under each other.

Comment: You have to consider the margins. Try dropping to 49%. They fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border on the item is creating a width greater than 50%. Add this to ensure this does not happen:

```
.container__item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/evOVvZ)

For better spacing, change this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){ 
  .container__item {
      width: 49%;
  }
}
```

Comment: what about the spacing in between?

Comment: @Alex Updated answer. You originally have 4 boxes at 24% (not 25%), so you need to pick a number lower than 50% in the media query, if that makes sense?

Comment: In fact you can just make the width 48% or something and omit the box-sizing property rule.